# asn1c keeps using long instead of INTEGER_t but I don't ask it for that

Tags: asn.1

Let I have an asn:

```
A ::= SEQUENCE {
    a INTEGER (0 .. 255),       
    b INTEGER (0 .. 255),       
    c INTEGER (0 .. 65535),     
    d INTEGER (0 .. 65535),
    e [0] INTEGER (0 ..255) OPTIONAL, 
    f[1] INTEGER (0 .. 63) OPTIONAL 
}
```

I compile it WITHOUT fnative-types, but code looks like

```
typedef struct A{
long     a;
long     b;
long     c;
long     d;
long    *e/* OPTIONAL */;
long    *f/* OPTIONAL */;

/* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} A_t;
```

Why so? It causes long DER byte sequence

Comment: cannot answer as I'm not familiar with the asn1c compiler. However, the DER encoding is guaranteed to be unique. So no matter the C-equivalent structure, the INTEGER fields will always be encoded with the least number of bytes required.

Answer (score 1):

To force structure creation by asn1c, use it with the `-fwide-types` option.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the ASN.1 compiler you're using you may be able to specify the C variable types used for structure fields.

In the Objective Systems toolset you can have an XML configuration file which is input to the compiler along with your ASN.1 schema. That allows you to tell the ASN.1 compiler what sort of integer should be used for a, b, c, etc.